# How do i get a sharing link for the app if I'm using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iOS app and i haven't bought the dev licence yet, my app is about facts and jokes based on a more categorised view. So i added a button to share the same using **UIActivityViewController** and the string I'm passing is the joke and an appended string which says **"Check out this app (in this place i want to include the app store's link so that others could connect to it)"**

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until your app is on the App Store, you can't guess its link. What you can do is, create a **landing website**, such as yourAppName.com, and directing users to this website on **Check out this app**. When your app will be on App Store, you'll provide a button with this link on the site to access your app, or just **make a redirect**.

On other way would be to make a request on this link : http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.acocagne.movidea and search for `trackViewUrl` in the response, which will correspond to the URL when your app will be on App Store.

Anyway, I think first solution is the easier.

Comment: Figured it out.Thanks buddy, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to have been helpful :)